# Python + MongoDB: How to connect to MongoDB from Python and write data?

Tags: python, mongodb

I would like to connect to MongoDB from a Python script and write data directly onto it. Would like the DB to be filled like so:

```
John
Titles    Values
color     black
age       15

Laly
Titles    Values
color     pink
age       20
```

Currently, it’s written to a .csv file like following, but would like to write it like so to MongoDB:

```
import csv

students_file = open(‘./students_file.csv’, ‘w’)
file_writer = csv.writer(students_file)

…

file_writer.writerow([name_title]) #John
file_writer.writerow([‘Titles’, ’Values’])
file_writer.writerow([color_title, color_val]) #In first column: color, in second column: black
file_writer.writerow([age_title, age_val]) #In first column: age, in second column: 15
```

What would be the right approach to connecting to MongoDB using Python, and write strings directly to MongoDB?

Thank you in advance, and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#Try this:
from pymongo import MongoClient

# connect to the MongoDB 
connection = MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:<port>')

# connect to test collection
db = connection.test

# create dictionary
student_record = {}

# save rec to dict
student_record = {'name': 'John Doe','grade': 'A+'}

#insert the record
db.test.insert(student_record)

# find all documents
results = db.test.find()

# display documents from collection
for record in results:
    out_name = str(record['name'])
    out_grade = str(record['grade'])
    print(out_name + ',' + out_grade)

# close the connection to MongoDB
connection.close()
```